# Excel - Creating UDF from a Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I often come across situations where I am writing very similar but verbose formulas that use the same range as an argument for multiple functions.

As a simple example, consider:

```
=(A+B)/B
```

Is there any easy way I could create a UDF such as:

```
=PCTCHANGE(A,B)
```

That could perform the exact same calculation as above?  I realize that with simple arithmetic operators this is trivial, but is there an easy way to wrap something more complex into a single easy function?

```
=IF(""=$U30,"",G30/IF(ROW(G30)-MONTH(U30)<ROW(K$8),G$5,OFFSET(G30,-MONTH(U30),0))-1)
```

I'd like to avoid translating the formula into Application.WorksheetFunction calls.  I assume Application.Evaluate is probably part of the solution, but I cannot figure out how to pass ranges into it through the UDF.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the UDF you have already attempted or are working with.

Comment: Could you edit your second formula to show complete absolute/relative references? Could G30 be $G30 like $U30? Could K$8 and G$5 be $K$8 and $G$5? The lack of absolute referencing on columns worries me that the formula may not work unless in a specific column.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to open up VBA and create a UDF from a Module.

Type ALT-F11 to open up the VBA editor.  Under your project, perform a right click and select Insert --> Module

Type the following into the VBA editor window

```
Function PctChange(A As Double, B As Double) As Double
   PctChange = (A + B) / B
End Function
```

When you call the function, do what you normally do.  In any cell type PctChange(CellA, Cell B).